# How do I accept a taanis dibbur on myself?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, speech-talking

In light of the recent tragedy in Kiryas Yovel (https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/israel-news/1670321/4-sifrei-torah-thrown-to-the-ground-kiryat-yovel-shul-vandalized.html) I have decided to accept a taanis dibbur on myself. How do I do this? Do i need to say any special prayers in the amida like we do with a normal fast or do I just start when I'm ready?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thank you for such an intriguing question. However, personal questions like this are not a good fit for this site and should be directed to your Rabbi.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) 
Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rabbi Matzliach Mazuz [paskens](https://www.ykr.org.il/question/5868) that you do not need to accept it at Mincha prior to starting it. So [paskens](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/5341) Rav Dov Lior, and Rav Ben Tzion Mutzafi([see here](http://www.doresh-tzion.co.il/QAShowAnswer.aspx?qaid=89509)).